# How to skip deleting some files when doing hugo deploy?

Tags: hugo

I want to avoid deleting some already existing files from my target S3 bucket when I run `hugo deploy` but I was not able to find any configuration options to tell it to skip removing some "unamanaged" files.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently is a bug so I raised it at https://github.com/gohugoio/hugo/issues/6681

Short-term workaround was to add `--maxDeletes 0` to disable deletion.